# Write spark event log to local filesystem instead of hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, filesystems, event-log

I want to redirect event log of my spark applications to a local directory like **"/tmp/spark-events"** instead of **"hdfs://user/spark/applicationHistory"**.

I set the `"spark.eventLog.dir"` variable to **"file:///tmp/spark-events"** in cloudera manager (Spark Client Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for spark-conf/spark-defaults.con).
But when I restart spark, spark-conf conatains **(spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://nameservice1file:///tmp/spark-eventstmp/spark)** and this not works.